# Tags "syntax" and "word-order"

Tags: discussion, tags

It was argued on a question once that [syntax](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) and [word-order](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-order) are not the same thing, yet I see these tags used both in the same questions.

What do the community think about this?

1. If they are the same thing, then we should remove one.
2. If they are not the same thing, then they shouldn't always be used in the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax includes word order as a subset. There are some aspects of syntax that are not merely about word order *per se*. Ellipsis, government, binding, etc. aren't (merely) about ordering of lexemes but nevertheless are parts of syntax. We can have discussions that were in-scope about syntax at a level of abstraction that does not refer directly to word order.  But word order is always about syntax.

I don't know what the SE policy is concerning tags that are supersets of other tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the two terms, plus *morphology*, are very often confused and, as a result, mixed. In the perfect world, *syntax* and *morphology* would be two separate branches, and *word order* would be one of the questions syntax deals with – the main one, I should think. In the real world, however, *morphology* and *word order* are, I would say, fine, but *syntax* can be used for anything ranging from 'word order' to 'word order + syntax + morphology'.

Personally, I don't support this merging in the slightiest, so my suggestion would be to manually correct uses of *syntax* where 'morphology' was meant, and maybe it would be also a good idea to incorporate *word order* into *syntax*?

Comment: Morphology is different from syntax, why do you think they're that correlated?

Comment: Clearly, my post was less clear than I thought. Hope it's better now. There's even a question about that here: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/836/what-meaningful-distinction-is-there-between-morphology-and-syntax/1497#1497.